# Solr 4.x identify document hit from statistic values or identify documents within results

Tags: apache, solr

I have a use case where I wish to identify the documents that match certain criteria within a set of results.

Lets say I have

```
ID, Price, Name
1,200, Banana
2,250, Apple
3,150, Pear
4,300, Orange
5,350, Lemon
```

I am looking for a way to flag which document is the lowest price, and which document is the highest price. I can identify the value using &stats=true&stats.field=price which will return

```
<min>150
<max>350
```

But I need it to tell me which document it is that was the lowest hit, and which was the highest hit (and in case where there are multiple documents with the same lowest or highest price value, then return the first).

For example

```
<min>150
 <ID>3
 <Price>150
 <Name>Pear
<max>350
 <ID>5
 <Price>350
 <Name>Lemon
```

Any ideas on how to get these values? I am focusing on the stats component but there may be some other way that is eluding me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this documentation there is no switch to get this from stats, http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent .

One way of doing that is , 
First send your stats query and keep the min and max value in your client code. 
Send two queries one, with price: your first query with rows=1 to get the document with min price and  with price: your first query with rows=1 to get the document with max price.

Second option is , using the grouping feature and read first and last document of the results:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&indent=true&fl=id,name,price&q=*:*&group=true&group.field=price&group.main=true&sort=price%20asc
```

Comment: Thanks. We are currently using multiple queries (your first option) and trying to cut that down, the second option is interesting but I think we need to essentially display all the results to get first and last value? If so, I have some queries with a few thousand results so it could get very messy.

Thanks